# tkinter widget not displaying when trying to execute it

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to practice my tkinter coding and I have a book that has an example inside it, but the example is not displaying the widgets, could you please share or let me know what I have left out, I have typed it out exactly as it is in the book, but I cannot see what is missing, the frame window displays with nothing inside it?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self)._init_(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self, text="choose your movie").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        Label(self, text="make selection").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.likes_comedy = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self, text="comedy", variable=self.likes_comedy, command=sefl.update_text).grid(row=0, column=0,
                                                                                                    sticky=W)
        self.likes_drama = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self, text="drama", variable=self.likes_drama, command=self.update_text).grida(row=0, column=0,
                                                                                                   sticky=W)
        self.likes_romance = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self, text="romance", variable=self.likes_romance, command=self.update_text).grid(row=4, column=0,
                                                                                                      sticky=W)
        self.results_txt = Text(self, width=40, height=5, wrap=WORD)
        self.results_txt.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3)

    def update_text(self):
        likes = ""
        if self.likes_comedy.get():
            likes += "you enjoy comedy.\n"
        if self.likes_drama.get():
            likes += "you maybe like drama.\n"
        if self.likes_romance.get():
            likes += "you like romance.\n"

        self.results_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.results_txt.insert(0.0, likes)


root.title("Mad Lib Assignment#2 Chapter#1")
root.geometry("600x400")
app = Frame(root)
lbl = Label(app, text="I am the label")

lbl.grid()
app.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using and what you are trying to achieve with that code.

Comment: here it is sorry guys....

Comment: there's a typo girda in drama checkbutton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not calling Application in your program, and many other mistakes, including the parameters in `super`, the double underscore in `super().__init__()`, typos, etc...

The following calls `Application`, displays widgets, and does not throw errors.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(master)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.grid()

    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self, text="choose your movie").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        Label(self, text="make selection").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.likes_comedy = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self, text="comedy", variable=self.likes_comedy, command=self.update_text).grid(row=0, column=2,
                                                                                                    sticky=W)
        self.likes_drama = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self, text="drama", variable=self.likes_drama, command=self.update_text).grid(row=0, column=3,
                                                                                                   sticky=W)
        self.likes_romance = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self, text="romance", variable=self.likes_romance, command=self.update_text).grid(row=4, column=0,
                                                                                                      sticky=W)
        self.results_txt = Text(self, width=40, height=5, wrap=WORD)
        self.results_txt.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3)

    def update_text(self):
        likes = ""
        if self.likes_comedy.get():
            likes += "you enjoy comedy.\n"
        if self.likes_drama.get():
            likes += "you maybe like drama.\n"
        if self.likes_romance.get():
            likes += "you like romance.\n"

        self.results_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.results_txt.insert(0.0, likes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.title("Mad Lib Assignment#2 Chapter#1")
    root.geometry("600x400")
    app = Application(root)
    lbl = Label(app, text="I am the label")

    lbl.grid()
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see there is another example in this book, I am going to type it out and post it later on, your answer has made me aware of more detailed things in the code that I could not see, still learning this tkinter layout and order, you are helpful...